# What is the autofac .OnActivated equivalent in DryIoc?

Tags: autofac, dryioc

In switching over from Autofac to DryIoc, I have a need to implement something akin to OnActivated.

Given the following class

```cs
public interface IService
{
    void DoStuff {}
}
public class SomeService : IService
{
    public void DoStuff() {}
    public void Init(){}
}
```

My autofac registration would look like this

```cs
builder.RegisterType<SomeService>()
     .As<IService>()
     .OnActivated(x => x.Instance.Init())
     .SingleInstance();
```

What would the equivalent of this look like in DryIoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RegisterInitializer` will be the closest equivalent, check the [docs](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/RegisterResolve.md#registerinitializer).

But it is just a sugar on top of very powerful DryIoc [Decorators](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/Decorators.md). So I suggest to look more deeply into them.